# Twitter integration for iOS 7, cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter, cocos2d-iphone

I've looked up numerous tutorials online, and for Facebook/Twitter integration I keep getting stopped by this same error.

From the code below (which is used in the tutorial), I get the error *no visible @interface for 'MainScene' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'*. Spent a couple hours on this and I really don't understand whats going on. Below is the relevant code:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Tweeting from my own app! :)"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Stuff you need to know for a Cocos2d-v3 app

- `UIViewController` objects define the `presentViewController` interface
- `CCScene` objects are not `UIViewController` objects
- Your `CCScene` objects live in a layer in the `rootViewController` which never changes

Imagine it like so

rootViewController -> Cocos2d -> [Main Scene] or [Paused Scene] or [GameOverScene]

### What this means for you

You have to access this `rootViewController` and present your tweet sheet or other `UIViewController`. Here is how you access the root view controller in any iOS app :

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

### Code for your problem

The people behind Cocos anticipated this use case and made a short hand for this command. Here is how you should present ViewControllers in your Cocos app :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:yourTwitterVC animated:YES];
```

Hope you have a better understanding of the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

This situation has no any conclusions with some Social frameworks. It looks like syntax error. Please provide MORE code if you can.